# How can I find the part of cmd.exe that processes windows batch commands before they're executed?

Tags: windows, debugging, x64dbg, command-line

I'm able to find the ReadConsoleInputW commands for pause and reading input for commands but I'm unable to find the actual processing of the commands. I'm using x64dbg but I'm fairly new to Reverse Engineering. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please give some examples of "batch commands" you are looking for.

Comment: Generally, without knowing what specifically is being looked for, you can list the string references for `cmd.exe` (there can be multiple), find the command you want, and set a breakpoint on the instructions that reference it. Once you resume the process, type the command you want (which should trigger one of your breakpoints). If you traverse up the callstack some number of frames, you should find a function that contains the scope for the "processing of the commands". If you're looking for the parser, specifically, there's another (similar) pattern you can use.